# How to implement a Core Data virtual attribute properly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an integer 16 attribute (location) in the CoreData datamodel,
but the integer is just a flag, I want to read/write as an NSString when using instances of the class.

How should I implement this while keeping to the rules of managed objects?

Do I need still need to have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *location;
/////
@dynamic location;
```

or can I do something like this:

```
@interface Game : NSManagedObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;
@end

@interface Game(PrimitiveAccessors)
- (NSNumber *)primitiveLocation;
- (void)setPrimitiveLocation:(NSNumber *)newLocation;
@end

@implementation Game

@dynamic location;

- (NSString *)location
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"location"];

    NSString *location = nil;
    if ([self primitiveLocation] == 0)
    {
        location = @"Home";
    }
    if ([self primitiveLocation] == 1)
    {
        location = @"Away";
    }

    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"location"];

    return location;
}

- (void)setLocation:(NSString *)newLocation
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"location"];

    if (newLocation == @"Home")
    {
        [self setPrimitiveLocation:0];
    }
    if (newLocation == @"Away")
    {
        [self setPrimitiveLocation:1];
    }

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"location"];
}

@end
```

Comment: This looks like a job for NSValueTransformer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the string names in a plist, or accessible constants, or local array?

For instance:
0 --> [stringValues objectAtIndex:0] -->"home"
1 --> [stringValues objectAtIndex:1] -->"away"

Let's say down the road you want to change the text "home" and "away", if you represent the string (via constant or array or whatever, not saved in core data) with the persistent int, you can keep your strings consistent, and have the ability to change.

Kind of like a key-->value thing.

Answer (score 0):

The location property should be of type NSString *